# C++ structs and arrays on stack and heap, values, references, and dereferencing questions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a bit rusty at this. I'm trying to figure out exactly what happens with object declaration, values and references, stack and heap. I know the basics, but am unsure about the following examples:

```
struct MyObject
{
    int foo;
    MyObject(int val)
    {
        foo = val;
    }  

    MyObject()//[EDIT] default constructor
    {
    }
}

//...

//1)
//this reserves memory on the stack for MyObject0 and initializes foo:
MyObject a = MyObject(1); //[EDIT] fixed from comments

//2)
MyObject* b = new MyObject(2);//This I know reserves memory on the heap,  
//returns a pointer to it (and calls constructor). 
//There are also other ways like malloc or memset.

//3)
MyObject c = *(new MyObject(3));// So here we instantiate MyObject on the heap, 
//return a pointer to it but the pointer is dereferenced outside the parenthesis. 
//Is c now a newly created value type copy on the stack? 
//And is the original new MyObject(3) now inaccessible in the heap memory (leaked) 
//because the pointer to it was never stored?

//4)
// void myFunc( MyObject c){}
myFunc(c); //Am I doing a member-wise assignment from c to a new function-scope 
//temporary MyObject reserved somewhere else in memory (in a stack frame?)? 
//Or am I somehow passing a reference to c even though c is not a pointer or reference?
//[EDIT] myFunc(c); would pass as a reference if I had void myFunc( MyObject &c){}
```

Finally, if I have a `MyObject[] myObjArr1 = new MyObject[10]()` I have 10 uninitialized MyObject structs on the heap, and a pointer of type `MyObject` Array on the heap as well.

How do I declare a MyObject array, on the stack, where the MyObject structs within the array are also on the stack? Or is that not a thing you do?

Comment: **(1)** `MyObject a;` wouldn't compile, as `MyObject` lacks default constructor. *"Does it also call a default constructor here?"* It would if one existed. Your conclusions for **(2)** and **(3)** are correct. **(4)** The parameter of `myFunc` is copy-initialized from `c`. Since `MyObject` lacks a user-defined copy constructor, the compiler-generated one indeed performs member-wise copy initialization.

Comment: @Tudor, does the line MyObject a; compiles ? it shouldn't, since you defined your own constructor, the default constructor should not be available for you.

Comment: You are correct. So this would only compile if I did not have a constructor defined,

Comment: `MyObject[] myObjArr1 = new MyObject[10]` won't compile either.

Comment: *"How do I declare a MyObject array, on the stack"* You don't, not without a default constructor. If there were one, you would simply write `MyObject myObjArr[10];`

Comment: @Tudor Array on the stack allocated the following way:
MyObject myObjArr1[10]; (assuming default constructor is available)
The array size must be known at compile time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @feldi So all I need is a default constructor `MyObject(){}` in my struct, and then then a `MyObject myObjArr[10]` would actually hold its MyObject structs on the stack? Cool.

Comment: Well I guess you've all promptly answered all my questions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me re-comment on a more precise way:

1) This creates an `a` variable on the stack initializing it with the value of the temporary `MyObject(1)`, that is created on the stack as a `MyObject` calling `MyObject::MyObject(1)` as constructor. The compiler may eliminate the intermediate steps.  You can do it simply as `MyObject a(1);`  Note: the `=` is not an assignment

2) Creates a `MyObject` on heap by calling `MyObject::MyObject(2)` and returns a pointer to it, used initialize the `b` pointer.

> Forget about `malloc` and `memset`: they allocate memory, but DON'T
>   CONSTRUCT objects. The sooner you will forgot them, the better for you
>   and anybody else.

3) a `Myobject` is created on the heap and constructed by calling `Myobkect::Myobject(3)`, then The `new` returned pointer is dereferenced and the resulting value used to initialize `c` by copy.  The on-heap created object is "forgotten" in there. (Memory leak: you have no chance to access it further)

4) The object `c` is copied in the local parameter `c` of `myFunc` (in fact the two `c` are two distinct objects) that will exist into the stack up to the function exit.

Comment: Props for the `MyObject a(1);` explanation. Eliminatable temporary values, and values constructed by new.